# Nodemailer, Gmail: Node Rest API

Tags: rest, gmail, nodemailer

I have node rest APIs developed. I want to fetch the single data by _id and then pass that data to the specified gmail address using nodemailer. I am not able to properly apply it. Here's my API code for products controller:

```
exports.products_get_product = (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.productId;
  Product.findById(id)
    .select("senderName senderPhone senderEmail pickupAddr receiverName receiverPhone deliveryAddr note _id ")
    .exec()
    .then(doc => {
      console.log("From database", doc);
      if (doc) {

          res.status(200).json({
          product: doc,
          request: {
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://courierapp-test.herokuapp.com/products"
          }

        });
      } else {
        res
          .status(404)
          .json({ message: "No valid entry found for provided ID" });
      }

      var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        secure: false,
        auth: {
          user: '****@gmail.com',
          pass: '****'
        }
      });

      var mailOptions = {
        from: '',
        to: '',
        subject: doc.note,
        html: '<p>'+ doc.senderName + '</p>'
              '<p>'+ doc.senderPhone + '</p>' +
              '<p>'+ doc.senderEmail + '</p>' +

      };


      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        } else {
          console.log('Email sent: ' + JSON.stringify(info.res));
        }
      });

    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    });
};
```

I have included my mongoDb login credentials into the auth. When I tried running these on local I get the console error:

{"code":"ECONNECTION","command":"CONN"}

And after deploying them on heroku, my application crashes hence unable to check it on server. Kindly help with valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that nodemailer requires at least the 'to' to contain one valid email address.